# Bing custom search - Unable to pin multiple related articles

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, bing-custom-search

I'm working on POC for the Bing custom search. The requirement is to rank articles in a particular order.

For ex: Let's say when I search for 'Foo', It might then return the articles list/ result as:

```
Foo1
Foo2
Foo3
Foo4
Foo5
Foo6
```

However I might find that Foo5 should be on top and Foo4 should be next, then followed by Foo6. So expected order of articles is:

```
Foo5
Foo4
Foo6
Foo1
Foo2
Foo3.
```

I can bring the Foo5 to top by using pin to top. However the query doesn't allow me to pin the rest of the articles in that order for the same query.

Is there a way to group of articles to one query? Or is this feature missing in Bing custom search?

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not available in Bing. Microsoft has now updated their documentation and we can only pin one item. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-custom-search/define-your-custom-view#pin-slices-to-the-top-of-search-results